# Azure SQL Server VM OR Azure Windows Server with SQL Server install

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm looking to provision two Enterprise SQL Servers in an AlwaysOn configuration with a 3rd Enterprise SQL Server as a DEV machine using Microsoft Azure. The two options I'm considering are Azure SQL Server VM images or Azure Windows Server VM with SQL Server licensed and installed separately.

What are the advantages and disadvantages for both options? Purely from a cost perspective the Azure SQL Server VM's are cheaper for the first two years. After 2 years the Windows Servers with SQL Server Installed are cheaper to maintain. The upfront licensing is very expensive, after which we're simply paying for Software Assurance renewals.

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question: "Azure VM + SQL Server" for long-term cost-effectiveness, or "Azure SQL Server VM" for short-term savings. However, have you considered using "Azure SQL" itself for production use? That would be the cheapest (though still requires a local SQL Server for dev, but that wouldn't be on Azure, and you can use Express or Developer editions for that).

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the quick reply. I've looked into Azure SQL the issue was it did not offer SSRS, SQL Agent, or CLR Integration. We could provision a separate SQL Server instance to run those tasks. I feel as though there would be a bit more maintenance (and performance issues) doing so.

Comment: Aside from cost are there any other pros/cons? Azure SQL Server seems much easier to maintain as we don't need to consider licensing every year or whenever we provision new resources.

Comment: You could run SSRS locally and have it target the Azure SQL server (assuming this is a supported scenario, I don't actually know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you're comparing using the SQL Server Gallery images in the portal vs using a Windows Server image and manually installing SQL Server using your own license.

With regards to cost, you answered the question. 
The only other consideration is that the SQL Server Gallery images are recognized by Azure as such and thus allow you to leverage Portal features like Automated Backup, Automated Patching, Monitoring of SQL Perf counters, etc.

BTW, if you haven't, try the SQL AlwaysOn Portal Template in the Gallery. 
It provisions a whole AlwaysOn deployment end-to-end.

Comment: Thanks @LuisVargas, we actually decided to go with the Azure templates; no licensing and ultimate flexibility. We're going to use the SQL AlwaysOn template too.